# Cannot read property 'style/ css/ attr/ setAttribute' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I tried to resize a svg (which i did put into the div). I tried out:

```
    document.getElementById('pload').setAttribute("height", "15%");

    document.getElementById('pload').css("height", "15%");

    document.getElementById('pload').attr("height", "15%");

    document.getElementById('pload').style.height = "15%";
```

I always get "Cannot read property 'style/ css/ attr/ setAttribute' of null.". I can interact with document.getElementById('pload') but can't change any style properties. Everything should already be loaded (see JS: EventListener). Else there are just some timers in the function, nothing should interfere with the svg/div (i just change some style properties in the svg with jquery, no id's or var's are shared. Can interact with svg id's just fine, "EventListener" "load" also works fine). I have no idea anymore what this problem could be.

**HTML:**

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="pload">
           //svg (#pagepreload) here
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
    #pagepreload *{
       visibility: hidden;
    }
    #pagepreload #mappin, #pagepreload #ring {
       visibility: visible;
    }
    #pagepreload{
       position: absolute;
       padding: 0;
       border: 0;
       margin: 0;
       height: 100%;
       transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
       left: 50%;
       top: 50%;
    }
    #pload{
       padding: 0;
       border: 0;
       margin: 0;
       position: relative;
       left: 50%;
       top: 50%;
       transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
       height: 30%;
       transition: top 1s ease-in-out, left 1s ease-in-out, height 1s ease-in-out, transform 1s ease-in-out;
    }
```

**JS:**

```
    window.addEventListener("load", afterload(), false);
    function afterload(){
       document.getElementById('pload').style.height = "15%";
       //timers here (accessing svg content)
    };
```

Thanks for your time and effort in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the `afterload` method when you are attaching it to the `load` event.

Do this instead:

```
window.addEventListener("load", afterload, false);
function afterload(){
    document.getElementById('pload').style.height = "15%";
    //timers here (accessing svg content)
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Your script loaded before dom parse.

Use `defer` to solve this problem.

```
<script src="script.js" defer></script>
```

Or use your script link before end of body tag.